# Codename One - change UIID dynamically

Tags: codenameone

Is there a way to dynamically change the Font size of a UIID?

(I have my sizes in pixels and I need to adapt the font to different screen sizes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why change it dynamically and not define the font size in millimeters in the theme to begin with?

The "right way" to do this is to define multiple UIID's in your theme and just call `setUIID()`with the right size see https://www.codenameone.com/manual/theme-basics.html

You can use [getAllStyles()](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Component.html#getAllStyles--) to change the UIID of a specific component manually.

Comment: That is what I am doing right now. I have different UIIDs, but that means I have to set the new UIID for every single component. By changing the UIID I wanted to do it just once. I will try the milimeters. Thank you.